# Sorting according to version numbers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I am sorting the folders in a directory according to *version* numbers and removing the old ones. 
The problem I am having is thanks to octopus deploy's versioning standard. If you release a project with the same version multiple times, the numbers will look like this;

---

```
1.3.5.6
1.3.5.6_1
1.3.5.6_2
1.3.5.7
```

---

And those underscores are killing my algorithm. My function as follows;

```
function CleanUp-Files ($col,$NumberToSave) {
  foreach ($pkg in $col.FullName) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $pkg |
    Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer} |
    Sort-Object { [version]($_.Name -replace '^(\d+(\.\d+){1,3})(_\d{1,2})?$', '$1') } -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip $NumberToSave |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
  }
}
```

What can I do to accommodate those underscores into my sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort-Object can execute on more than one argument.

```
Sort-Object { [Version]($_ -replace '_.*$') }, { if ($_ -match '_') { [Int]($_ -replace '^.*_') } else { 0 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the `Name` property by `_` - output the first part as a `[version]` object first, then the suffix last:

```
... |Sort-Object { 
        $version,$suffix = $_.Name -split '_'
        $version -as [version]
        if($suffix){$suffix} 
}
```

Comment: Your code returned wrong output, when I used a different data set. It thought 3.0.2.2 is a bigger version than 3.0.2.13_3 or even 3.0.2.13. Maybe we are missing something here. Chris Dent's answer sorted them correctly. But thanks since I learned something from you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would multiply the revision with 100 and add the number after the underscore:

```
function CleanUp-Files ($col,$NumberToSave) {
    $rex = [regex]'(.*\.)(\d+)_?(\d+)?'
    $callback = {  
        param($match) 
        '{0}{1}' -f $match.Groups[1].Value , ([int]$match.Groups[2].Value * 100 +[int]$match.Groups[3].Value) 
        }
  foreach ($pkg in $col.FullName) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $pkg |
    Where-Object {$_.PsIscontainer} |
    Sort-Object { [version]($rex.Replace($_.Name, $callback)) } -Descending |
    Select-Object -Skip $NumberToSave |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Verbose
  }
}
```

---

A simple demo:

```
$versions = '1.3.5.6', '1.3.5.6_1', '1.3.5.6_2', '1.3.5.7'

$rex = [regex]'(.*\.)(\d+)_?(\d+)?'
$callback = {  
    param($match) 
    '{0}{1}' -f $match.Groups[1].Value , ([int]$match.Groups[2].Value * 100 +[int]$match.Groups[3].Value) 
    }

$versions | ForEach-Object {
    [version]($rex.Replace($_, $callback))
}
```

will give you:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
1      3      5      600     
1      3      5      601     
1      3      5      602     
1      3      5      700
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use this later somewhere else